# Whats an example of a flags(flags module) ajax call back for authcache in drupal?

Tags: ajax, drupal, authentication, caching, flags

I have multiple different flags in different regions of a page, and with authcache they are all showing the state of the user that initally cached the page. The flag link form token breaks so clicking the flag throws an error. I was wondering if anyone had an example of the best way to retrieve and replace all the flag links via ajax so they work again. Thanks!